# .Is it possible to have create local repositories using CUrl commands in JFrog?

Tags: api, repository, local, jfrog-cli

I have hosted JFrog-OSS docker container which is running behind Nginx along with DNS attached to it .I want to create new repositories(local ones) using REST Apis (curl commands ) .Since it's a free version .Is it possible to have create local repositories using CUrl commands in JFrog ?.

```
curl -s -uadmin:password -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://devops.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/path/to/directory/ -d  '

[ {
  "\key"\ : "\example-repo-local"\,
  "\description"\ : "\artifactory repository"\,
  "\type"\ : "\LOCAL"\,
  "\url"\ : "\https://devops.com/artifactory/example-repo-local"\,
  "\packageType"\ : "\Generic"\
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating repositories via REST API requires Artifactory Pro.

Also, the url and JSON configurations seems wrong.
The url that the request is sent to should not include path, but a repository only.

The "type" key should be "rclass". "url" key is only for remote.

See [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateRepository) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the reply .Understood that REST APIs feature is only available for Pro version not for OSS version .

Comment: Not all the REST APIs are only for pro. The documentation specifies for each API if it's for Pro only - "Notes: Requires Artifactory Pro". Other API should work for OSS